# Why doesn't my custom library load?

Tags: 8

I am trying to load libraries in my Drupal 8 site, but it does not seem to be working. Here is my library yaml, is this correct? Why can't I load dexp.slides?

```
dexp.slides
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:   
      css/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
      css/admin.style.css: {}
      css/plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css: {}
  js:
    js/dexp.layerslider.js:  {}
    js/plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:  {}
    js/plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:  {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui.draggable
    - core/jquery.ui.dropable
    - core/jquery.ui.sortable
    - core/jquery.ui.dialog 
    - core/jquery.ui.tab
```

I am trying the above way but the dependencies are not being loaded.

Comment: There are other ways to include custom js files in D7. The one that I prefer is context_add_assets (https://www.drupal.org/project/context_addassets). This will allow adding css/js based on context.

Comment: Question is for Drupal 8 though

Comment: @clive english is my second language and it will take some time before my questions matches the required standard, at the same time answer by kevin helped me .

Comment: If it fixed your issue, please vote/accept so others who land here can see that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon after depx-slides:

```
dexp.slides:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:   
      css/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
      css/admin.style.css: {}
      css/plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css: {}
  js:
    js/dexp.layerslider.js:  {}
    js/plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:  {}
    js/plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:  {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui.draggable
    - core/jquery.ui.dropable
    - core/jquery.ui.sortable
    - core/jquery.ui.dialog 
    - core/jquery.ui.tab
```

The YAML is pretty strict about format. You can run it through a linter like [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/) - that is how I noticed the colon was missing.

After making that change, clear your cache and require your library (either in the info file or by attaching it with #attached or attach_library in a twig file) it should work.

The [official docs page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) has all the info you need about attaching libraries, but the YAML must always be correctly formatted.

That [YAML Lint tool](http://www.yamllint.com/), by the way, works for any YAML. If you ever work on a routing, permission or other YAML files, it can check if it is valid or not which is the first step to debugging YAML - simply eyeballing it is not good enough - use the tool that will just *tell you*. There is an [npm package available](https://github.com/rasshofer/yaml-lint) to run it from command line (I do recommend).