# Drupal 8: javascript not loading in theme

Tags: theming, 8, javascript

I would like to add a little javascript to my bootstrap child-theme, but is not loading.

These are the configuration files:

child.info.yml :

```
 core: 8.x
type: theme
base theme: bootstrap

name: 'child'
description: 'Uses the jsDelivr CDN for all CSS and JavaScript. No source files or compiling is necessary and is recommended for simple sites or beginners.'
package: 'Bootstrap'

regions:
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  navigation_collapsible: 'Navigation (Collapsible)'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'

libraries:
  - 'child/global-styling'
```

child.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
      css/masonry.css: {}
      css/basic-page.css: {}   

  js:
  js/main.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 300) {
                $("#navbar").addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $("#navbar").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: instead of using '$' sign use 'jQuery'

Comment: no, that didn't work

Comment: The JavaScript needs to be compatible with Drupal by wrapping it in an anonymous closure and passing in the $ variable. Consult the docs on writing JS and Drupal behaviors for an example

Comment: Also I'm betting your YAML isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: indeed, when i updated my YAML the javascript was loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 300) {
                $("#navbar").addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $("#navbar").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

to

```
Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
   attach: function (context, settings) {
   (function($) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 300) {
                $("#navbar").addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $("#navbar").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        });
   })(jQuery);
  }
```

};

Comment: Get rid of document ready and use Drupal.behaviors.

Comment: @Kevin it's better solution,I update the answer

Comment: Making it a behavior is equivalent of "document ready"

Comment: @Kevin thanks, I know that. but sometimes in debugging it's better to bypass  layers to find the bug faster.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: @jimi good, I'm happy it works for you and resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

One, YAML has to be properly formatted. [In another question, I recommended using YAML Lint](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/230896/57) to ensure you have the right structure.

Should be:

```
global-styling: 
  css: 
    theme: 
      css/basic-page.css: {}
      css/masonry.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
  dependencies: 
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
  js: 
    js/main.js: {}
```

Also, it is best to split your style and Javascript into two definitions but I suppose thats up to you.

Two, your [Javascript has to be compatible with Drupal per the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).

Instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 300) {
                $("#navbar").addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $("#navbar").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

What you want is:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.windowScroll = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 300) {
                $("#navbar").addClass('smaller');
            } else {
                $("#navbar").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        });
      });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

> Note: Since Drupal uses jQuery.noConflict() and only loads JavaScript
>   files when required, to use jQuery and the $ shortcode for jQuery you
>   must include jQuery and Drupal as dependencies in the library
>   definition in your MODULE.libraries.yml and add a wrapper around your
>   function.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
     $(context).find('input.myCustomBehavior').once('myCustomBehavior').each(function () {
      // Apply the myCustomBehaviour effect to the elements only once.
    });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your-theme.libraries.yml file:**

```
base:

 version: 1.x

js:

 js/main.js: {}
```

**In your-theme.info.yml file:**

```
libraries:

 - 'your-theme/global-styling'

 - 'your-theme/base'
```

Try  above method worked on my previous drupal8 website, i think your js file is not loading.

Also place a js folder in your bootstrap subtheme along with your main.js file